# Not able to fecth the rdetails using ng-repeat in Angular js

Tags: asp.net, angularjs

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>

        <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>
        <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </html>
```

what is the issue in the code?
not able to fecth the-rdetails of employee using ng-repeat in Angular js
    i m getting this ouput Id   Name    Gender  Salary
    {{employee.id}}     {{employee.name}}   {{employee.gender}}     {{employee.salary 
    what is the issue in the code?

Comment: Add your controller's code

Comment: @BillP var app = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.post('EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees')
            .then(function (response) { 
                $scope.employees = response.data;
        });

});

Comment: @BillP i m also getting 304 Not Modified status code

Comment: Any console errors?

Comment: @BillP Uncaught ReferenceError: angular is not defined
    at Script.js:1

Comment: @BillP Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$injector/modulerr?p0=myModule&p1=Error%3A%20%5B%24injector%3Ano

Comment: @BillP now  i m getting error in console@angular.js:15567 Error: [$http:badreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$http/badreq?p0=%

Comment: Try with `$http.get()` instead of `$http.post()`.

Comment: @BillP i have already used $http.get  then also getting the same error

Comment: @BillP var app = angular
    .module("myModule", [])
    .controller("myController", function ($scope, $http) {
        $http.get({
            type: 'GET'
            url: 'EmployeeService.asmx/GetAllEmployees'
        })
            .then(function (response) { 
                $scope.employees = response.data;
            });
    });

Comment: pass only the url as a string : `$http.get('your url')`

Comment: @BillP This is new error Id Name Gender Salary
{{employee.id}} {{employee.name}} {{employee.gender}} {{employee.salary}} in table border =1

Comment: @BillP Additional information to u this is my web.config <?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="DBCS"
         connectionString="server=DIWAKAR-PC\SQLEXPRESS;database=youtube;integrated security=SSPI"/>
    </connectionStrings>
  <system.web>
    <webServices>
      <protocols>
        <add name="HttpGet"/>
        </protocols>
     </webServices>
    </system.web>
</configuration>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to place angularjs script before controller script:

```
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>

    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"> 
    </script>
    <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>

    <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
</head>
```

Comment: now i m getting error in console angular.js:15567 Error: [$http:badreq] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.8/$http/badreq?p0=%7B%22type%22%3A%22GET%22%2C%22url%22%3A%22EmployeeService.asmx%2FGetAllEmployees%22%7D

Answer (score 0):

Just Use proper flow and structuring:

```js
var app = angular.module("myApp", []);

  app.controller('myController', function($scope){
  

  $scope.employees = [
    { id : 100,
      Name : 'ONE'
      },
    { id : 102,
      Name : 'TWO'
      }
  ];
  console.log("hi");
  console.log($scope.employees);
  });
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head >
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.1.5" data-semver="1.1.5" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
</script>
    
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script src="script.js"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-app="myApp">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.Name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.7.8/angular.min.js"></script>
        <link href="Style.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
        <script src="Scripts/Script.js"></script>

    </head>
    <body ng-app="myModule">
        <div ng-controller="myController">
            <table>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Id</th>
                        <th>Name</th>
                        <th>Gender</th>
                        <th>Salary</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr ng-repeat="employee in employees">
                        <td>{{employee.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.name}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.gender}}</td>
                        <td>{{employee.salary}}</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </html>
```

Comment: Use proper Angular js CDN as the initial script Reference ..for more Best practices visit angularjs.io